# How to record a call using freeswitch from terminal?

Tags: freeswitch

How to record a call in freeswitch using terminal,should I have to change the dialplan configuration or can somebody explain the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use "uuid_record" API call

```
freeswitch@media1.kazoo> uuid_record 
-USAGE: <uuid> [start|stop|mask|unmask] <path> [<limit>]
```